# Magento 2: How to get certification of Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, certification

Anyone used to get certification of Magento 2.

May you show me how to get certification of Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can check details from magento site. [magento certifications link](https://learning.adobe.com/certification.html)

[Magento Certifications for Developer](https://learning.adobe.com/certification.html?solution=Adobe%20Magento%20Commerce&language=English)

**1. Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Order Management Developer**

**2. Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Developer**

**3.
Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Business Practitioner**

**4. Adobe Certified Professional—Magento Commerce Developer**

**5. Adobe Certified Master Magento Commerce Architect**

**6.
Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Front-End Developer**

**7.
Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce JavaScript Developer**

**6.
Adobe Certified Expert Magento Commerce Cloud Developer**

Answer (score 42):

**1. Before appearing for the exam we need to prepare the for the exam**

- ***Examination Syllabus Details***

  - [AD0-E700 Adobe Certified Expert Magento Commerce Business Practitioner](https://spark.adobe.com/page/87jLctNB6KxM0/) (previously - Magento 2 Certified Solution Specialist)
  - [AD0-E702 Adobe Certified Professional - Magento Commerce Developer](https://spark.adobe.com/page/saM506xrYKi0p/) (previously Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer)
  - [AD0-E701 Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Front-End Developer](https://spark.adobe.com/page/lJWBfPhvp5npA/) (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional Front End Developer)
  - [AD0-E703 Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Developer](https://spark.adobe.com/page/OwpmK2JcACwhl/) (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer)
  - [AD0-E705 Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce JavaScript Developer](https://spark.adobe.com/page/ZDus3If2u1rQf/) (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional JavaScript Developer)
  - [AD0-E706 Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Cloud Developer](https://spark.adobe.com/page/GrkbPktpWMkkb/) (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional Cloud Developer)
  - [AD0-E707 Adobe Certified Expert Magento Commerce Order Management Developer](https://spark.adobe.com/page/K2Wjl6Na3BY0h/) (previously Magento 2 Certified Order Management Developer)
  - [AD0-E704 Adobe Certified Master Magento Commerce Architect](https://spark.adobe.com/page/PTidDHsT5JgyB/) (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer Plus)
- ***Premium ($$) Study Materials and Mock Tests (By [Swift Otter](https://swiftotter.com/))***

  - [AD0-E700 Adobe Certified Expert Magento Commerce Business Practitioner](https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-solution-specialist-exam-study-guide#/) (previously - Magento 2 Certified Solution Specialist)
  - [AD0-E702 Adobe Certified Professional - Magento Commerce](https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-associate-study-guide#/) Developer(previously Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer)
  - [AD0-E701 Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Front-End Developer](https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-frontend-developer-study-guide#/) (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional Front End Developer)
  - [AD0-E703 Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Developer](https://spark.adobe.com/page/OwpmK2JcACwhl/) (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer)
  - [AD0-E705 Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce JavaScript Developer](https://swiftotter.com/certifications/magento-2-javascript-developer-study-guide#/) (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional JavaScript Developer)
  - [AD0-E706 Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Cloud Developer](https://swiftotter.com/certifications/magento-2-cloud-developer-study-guide#/) (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional Cloud Developer)
  - [AD0-E704 Adobe Certified Master Magento Commerce Architect](https://swiftotter.com/certifications/magento-2-professional-developer-plus-study-guide#/) (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer Plus)
- ***Free / Open Source Materials***

  - **AD0-E706 Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Cloud Developer (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional Cloud Developer)**

    - [Magento Cloud Notes](https://github.com/magento-notes/magento2-cloud-developer-notes)
    - [Cloud Developer Mock Questions](https://www.goconqr.com/en/quiz/17576116/cloud-developer-exam-test-01-magento-2-certified-professional)
  - **AD0-E704 Adobe Certified Master Magento Commerce Architect (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer Plus)**

    - [Magento Developer Plus Study Notes](https://github.com/roma-glushko/magento2-dev-plus-exam)
  - **AD0-E702 Adobe Certified Professional - Magento Commerce Developer (previously Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer)**

    - [Associate Developer Study Notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1t61AugL-wE2B7uBzw5ak_ZQTo3Yju_sjb42ecjnWkpc/edit)
  - **AD0-E703 Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Developer (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer)**

    - [magento-lucknow/certification-notes](https://magento-lucknow.github.io/certification-notes/)
    - [magento-notes/magento2-exam-notes](https://github.com/magento-notes/magento2-exam-notes)
    - [df2k2/m2cert](https://github.com/df2k2/m2cert.git)
    - [Decimadigital Mock Questions](https://m2exam.decimadigital.com/learning-magento-2-training-with-questions-list)
    - [colinmurphy/magento-exam-notes](https://github.com/colinmurphy/magento-exam-notes) (Outdated)
  - **AD0-E701 Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Front-End Developer (previously Magento 2 Certified Professional Front End Developer)**

    - [Frontend Developer Training Material by FishEye](https://github.com/fisheye-academy/m2cpfed-training)
    - [Frontend Developer Mock Questions](https://www.goconqr.com/p/15702242-magento-2-front-end-developer-certification-practice-exam-quizzes)
  - ***Other Paid Magento Training Materials***

    - [Magento trainings on the Adobe Digital Learning Platform](https://learning.adobe.com/catalog.html?solution=Adobe%20Magento%20Commerce)
    - [Magemastery](https://magemastery.net/)
    - [Magento training by Yireo](https://www.yireo.com/magento)
    - [M.academy](https://m.academy/)
    - [Mage2TV](https://www.mage2.tv/)

**2. Exam Vouchers**

- [Exam Voucher](https://market.xvoucher.com/adobe/home) (Get 50% discount on your first purchase using **Holiday22** coupon code. The promo is valid till December 31, 2022)

Comment: how to buy exam voucher now? i can't find any links on internet

Comment: Perfect answer!!! Easy to understand. Have saved this link for future ref. as well +1 :)

Comment: @hkguile added the voucher purchase links as well

Answer (score 2):

You can register for Magento 2 Certified Solution Specialist (Beta) exam.
Registration begins August 4 2017. Test dates for this Beta exam will be August 14-25.

More Info on registration and certification is available at:
https://u.magento.com/certification

Answer (score 1):

**MAGENTO 2 CERTIFIED SOLUTION SPECIALIST (BETA EXAM)** is from **August 14th to August 25th, 2017**

- This Beta exam will be limited to 200 registrants.
- exam at a discounted rate of $130
- 150 Multiple Choice items/180 minutes to complete the exam
- All questions are valid for Magento Community Edition (2.0.x/2.1.x) and Magento Enterprise Edition (2..0.x/2.1.x).

Register fast as this Beta exam will be limited to 200 registrants.

**Link** : https://u.magento.com/certification-magento2-solution-specialist-1

Answer (score 0):

MAGENTO 2 CERTIFIED SOLUTION SPECIALIST exam is available now please check below link

https://u.magento.com/certified-magento2-solution-specialist

You can also find study guide for `Magento 2` exam from this [link](https://magento-u.magento.com/magento-u/downloads/M2%20MCSS%20Cert%20Exam%20BETA%20Study%20Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Developer Certification is released.
https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer

Solution specialist certification also available
https://u.magento.com/certified-magento2-solution-specialist

Answer (score 0):

i would like to recommand you this all-in-one blog post:
https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-pass-the-magento-2-certification.html

it's a very good starting point to get a clear and concise overview of the official Magento Certification program with few pointers to good materials on internet (blogs, youtube channels, alternative options for training courses ..) to start your preparation.

also have a look at the official [Magento certification directory](https://u.magento.com/certification/directory) and try to get touch with those who already get certified in order to get feedback, hints, advises and some encouragement.

and last but not least START with the official devdocs.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased **Magento Certification Voucher (After Magento Purchase by Adobe )** from below link.

https://market.xvoucher.com/adobe

and you will get mail after successfully place voucher order.In that mail step by step info to book exam date on below site

https://auth.services.adobe.com/en_US/index.html/