# Preparing for Magento Certified Associate Developer

Tags: magento2, associatedevelopercertification

I am preparing for magento 2 associate developer certification but am not sure from where do i start it.
can anyone who has done this certification and can suggest me with the best study materials that, i could prefer for my certification as well as blogs that can be helpful.

****`Thanks In Advance`****

**Update**

Guyz Please add you suggestions as an ans so that other people will also get help from it.

Comment: 1.Brush up  your fundamentals of the magento. 
2.Go through the core working architecture of the magento.
3. Explore as much as you can 
4. Check for the dumps.

Comment: yes sir am spending lot of time on stack looking at ans and questions and trying to ans them in an appropriate manner

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/magento-notes/magento2-exam-notes

Comment: Thank you @PushpendraSingh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**To Prepare use the links below to get a study guide or try out a mock test:**

Practice Test -
Sample practice test for the Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer exam by SwiftOtter

https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-associate-developer-practice-test

Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer Study Guide -
A study guide by SwiftOtter for Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer exam [$]

https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-associate-study-guide

Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer Practice Test -
Sample practice test for the Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer exam by SwiftOtter

https://swiftotter.com/technical/magento-2-certified-developer-practice-test

Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer Study Guide -
A  study guide by SwiftOtter for Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer exam [$]

Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer Plus Practice Test -
Paid practice test for the Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer exam by SwiftOtter [$]

https://swiftotter.com/certifications/magento-2-certified-professional-developer-plus-practice-test/

Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer Plus Study Guide -
A paid study guide by SwiftOtter for Magento 2 Certified Professional Developer exam [$]

https://swiftotter.com/certifications/magento-2-professional-developer-plus-study-guide/

Free sample available for the first 2 chapter

Magento 2 Certified Solution Specialist Exam Study Guide -
A free study guide by SwiftOtter for Magento 2 Certified Solution Specialist exam

https://swiftotter.com/technical/magento-2-certified-solution-specialist-exam-study-guide

Magento 2 Certified Solution Specialist Practice Test -
Sample practice test for the Magento 2 Certified Solution Specialist exam by SwiftOtter

https://swiftotter.com/technical/magento-2-certified-solution-specialist-practice-test#take-test

Magento 2 Certified Frontend Developer Exam Study Guide -
A study guide by SwiftOtter for Magento 2 Certified Frontend Developer exam [$]

https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-frontend-developer-study-guide

Magento 2 Certified Cloud Developer Exam Study Guide -

https://swiftotter.com/certifications/magento-2-cloud-developer-study-guide/

**Magento2 Exam Notes**

- https://magento-lucknow.github.io/certification-notes/
- https://github.com/fisheye-academy/m2cpfed-training
- https://github.com/roma-glushko/magento2-dev-plus-exam
- https://github.com/magento-notes/magento2-exam-notes
- https://github.com/magento-notes/magento2-cloud-developer-notes
- https://github.com/df2k2/m2cert.git
- https://github.com/colinmurphy/magento-exam-notes
- [Magento 2 Associate Developer Exam notes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112052/magento-2-how-to-get-certification-of-magento-2)

**Mock Questions**

- https://www.goconqr.com/p/15702242-magento-2-front-end-developer-certification-practice-exam-quizzes
- https://www.goconqr.com/en/quiz/17576116/cloud-developer-exam-test-01-magento-2-certified-professional

JFYI: [Magento 2: How to get certification of Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112052/magento-2-how-to-get-certification-of-magento-2)

Comment: do anyone have dumps

Comment: yeah dump will be very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

**Refer to "examtask practice sets" for the "Magento2 Associate Developer" Exam dumps.**

Scenario-based questions here will help a lot to prepare for this certification exam. Free and paid both tests are available.

https://examtask.com/certifications/magento/magento2-certified-associate-developer-practice-test/

All the best!

Comment: thankss but i have already cleared this exam and its adobe certified commerce developer the name has been changed